# Consuming Dexie as a module

Tags: dexie

I'm just getting started with Dexie. I encountered an error I do not understand attempting to follow the Short Version example of [Consuming Dexie as a module](https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Consuming-dexie-as-a-module). I have the following source files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Dexie Test</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="./mytest.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

mydb.js

```
import Dexie from './dexie.js';

const db = new Dexie('myDb');
db.version(1).stores({
  friends: 'name, age'
});

export default db;
```

mytest.js

```
import db from './mydb.js';

console.log(db.name);
```

When I run this from a local web server, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './dexie.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the ES module version of Dexie you will need dexie.mjs instead of dexie.js from [https://unpkg.com/dexie@^3.0.0-rc.1/dist/dexie.mjs](https://unpkg.com/dexie@%5E3.0.0-rc.1/dist/dexie.mjs). Or if you pick it from node_modules, make sure you've installed dexie@next or dexie@^3.0.0-rc.1.

Comment: I also found the standard npm package contains dexie.es.js, which solves the issue as well. Excellent to hear that 3.0 is coming.